# How to handle error in a for loop (python) and continue execution

Tags: python

I m trying to get my script to still print action 2 "print (list1[3])" and skip action 1 "print (list1[9])" if it can not execute it. I aplozise in advnace if my question is not clear enough I m trying to do my best to explain the issue. I m a beginner.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','f']

try:
  for i in list1:
    #action 1
    print (list1[9])
    #action 2
    print (list1[3])
    break
except:
  pass
```

Comment: Just wrap the line in question in `try/except` rather than the whole loop.

Comment: @Sushanth the code can not print (print (list1[9])) because the list only contain 5 elements therefore it can not print the 9 element because it does not excite I want to skip that an still print the third one using print (list1[9]. right now my code can not do that. I m trying to fix it. I hope you understand what I mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this cleaner way

```
  l = ['a','b','c','d','f']

  # execute the function in try-except
  def try_to_do(fun, index):
     try:
        fun(l[index])
     except:
        pass

  for j in l:
     try_to_do(print, 11)
     try_to_do(print, 1)

  print('Done')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put a try for each action instead of both actions together, like this

```py
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','f']


for i in list1:
  try:
    #action 1
    print (list1[9])
  except IndexError:
    pass
  try:
    #action 2
    print (list1[3])
  except IndexError:
    pass
  break
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding single ```try..except``` block enough.. rather than adding to each condition.

Comment: @Sushanth Not to solve the problem, because if action1 fails then action2 won't execute

Comment: In general, you should try to catch specific errors Since you know you are expecting an `IndexError` you should catch that specifically with `except IndexError:`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I was focusing on answering his question without adding more detail which would make it harder to understand the answer, but you are correct.

Comment: @MarkMeyer How would I do that exactly? can you please provide a simple example?

Comment: @secatt just replace `except:` in the above answer with `except IndexError:` and it will only catch that specific error.

Comment: @MarkMeyer  like this ? because this is still not working  `list1 = ['a','b','c','d','f']

try:
  for i in list1:
    #action 1
    print (list1[9])
    #action 2
    print (list1[3])
    break
except IndexError:
  pass`

Answer (score 0):

Use try except inside the loop

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','f']

for i in list1:
    try:
        #action 1
        print (list1[9])
    except:
        print(e.with_traceback())
    try:
        #action 2
        print (list1[3])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.with_traceback())
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer Changed accordingly